# How to get the variables value from the methods of another class

Tags: java

I have a class called ReadFile which has a ReadFile function which then called another two methods which return the elements and numbers. How can I get these values from the ReadFile class in order for me to pass to the methods in main class?

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();

        ReadFile numbersFile = new ReadFile();
        numbersFile.readFile();

        preSortedList(numbers, elements);

        System.out.println();
        sortedList(numbers, elements);

} 


public class ReadFile {


   public void readFile(){

        File folder = new File("/Users/Mary/NetBeansProjects/Testing/src/program/pkg4/Input");

        for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
            try{
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                List<Integer> elements = getElements(reader);
                List<Integer> numbers = getNumbers(reader, elements);

                reader.close(); 
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("ERROR: There was a problem reading the file.\n" + e.getMessage());
            }  
        }
    }      

    public static List<Integer> getElements(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException{
        List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();
        String numberOfElement = reader.readLine();
        elements.add(Integer.parseInt(numberOfElement));
        return elements;
    }

    public static List<Integer> getNumbers(BufferedReader reader, List elements) throws IOException{
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        String line = reader.readLine();                  
        for (String s : line.split("\\s+")) {                        
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        }    
        return numbers;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Create two public List<Integer> mListOfElements , mListOfNumbers; globally in ReadFile Class, initialize it in readFile method. and store like mListOfElements = getElements(reader);, mListOfNumbers = getNumbers(reader,elements);

Now you can get by instance of that class, like numbersFile.mListOfElements and numbersFile.mListOfNumbers.

Answer (score 0):

In your ReadFile class create two member variables name elements and numbers then in your main method create the object of ReadFile class and get the values of its members using getters.

```
public class ReadFile {
    List<Integer> elements
    List<Integer> numbers

      //Constructors

     //create getter and setters here


    public void readFile(){

    File folder = new File("/Users/Mary/NetBeansProjects/Testing/src/program/pkg4/Input");

    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        try{
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            elements = getElements(reader);
            numbers = getNumbers(reader, elements);

            reader.close(); 
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("ERROR: There was a problem reading the file.\n" + e.getMessage());
        }  
    }
}      

public static List<Integer> getElements(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException{
    List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    String numberOfElement = reader.readLine();
    elements.add(Integer.parseInt(numberOfElement));
    return elements;
}

public static List<Integer> getNumbers(BufferedReader reader, List elements) throws IOException{
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    String line = reader.readLine();                  
    for (String s : line.split("\\s+")) {                        
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
    }    
    return numbers;
}
```

}

then in your main method

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    ReadFile numbersFile = new ReadFile();
    numbersFile.readFile();

    preSortedList(numbersFile.getNumbers(), numbersFile.getElements);

    System.out.println();
    sortedList(numbersFile.getNumbers(), numbersFile.getElements);
```

}

Comment: To initialize your members variables i.e. element and number arrays

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, there are 2 different ways of doing this.

**Approach 1**: using reference

Change `readFile()` method to accept numbers and elements list as input parameter.
Something like this:

```
public void readFile(List<Integer> numbers, List<Integer> elements){}
```

And in your main class, pass these two arguments:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();

    ReadFile numbersFile = new ReadFile();
    numbersFile.readFile(numbers,elements);
    preSortedList(numbers, elements);

    System.out.println();
    sortedList(numbers, elements);
}
```

And in your `readFile()` method:

```
public void readFile(List<Integer> numbers,List<Integer> elements) {
     File folder = new File("/Users/Mary/NetBeansProjects/Testing/src/program/pkg4/Input");

     for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
            try {
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                elements = getElements(reader);
                numbers  = getNumbers(reader, elements);

                reader.close(); 
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("ERROR: There was a problem reading the file.\n" + e.getMessage());
            }  
        }
    }
```

Here numbers and elements list passed from Main class shall have the updated values using the concept of reference.

**Approach 2**: using class member variables

Add 2 class members of type `List<Integer>` in your `ReadFile` class and create getters and setters for them:

```
public class ReadFile {
    List<Integer> elements;
    List<Integer> numbers;

     //getter and setters here

    public void readFile(){

    File folder = new File("/Users/Mary/NetBeansProjects/Testing/src/program/pkg4/Input");

    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            elements = getElements(reader);
            numbers = getNumbers(reader, elements);

            reader.close(); 
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("ERROR: There was a problem reading the file.\n" + e.getMessage());
        }  
    }
}
```

Now, in the main method, you can use the getters to use them.

There is yet another naive approach that can be used here.

**Approach 3**: using a collection/data structure to store value of the 2 list and return them.

```
public ArrayList<Integer>[] readFile(List<Integer> numbers,List<Integer> elements){

            File folder = new File("/Users/Mary/NetBeansProjects/Testing/src/program/pkg4/Input");

            for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
                try{
                    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                    elements = getElements(reader);
                    numbers  = getNumbers(reader, elements);

                    reader.close(); 
                }catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("ERROR: There was a problem reading the file.\n" + e.getMessage());
                }

    ArrayList<Integer>[] al = new ArrayList[2];             
    al[0] = elements;
    al[1] = numbers;

    return al;
            }
        }
```

And in the main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();

        ReadFile numbersFile = new ReadFile();
        List<Integer>[] al = numbersFile.readFile();

        elements = al[0];
        numbers = al[1];

        preSortedList(numbers, elements);

        System.out.println();
        sortedList(numbers, elements);

}
```

EDIT : Also, it seems that only the elements and numbers shall have values only from last file iteration only, as with each iteration, existing values gets over-written instead of getting appended with new value.

Need to change the private methods to handle the same.

```
public static List<Integer> getElements(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException{

// check if elements have been initialised or not. If not then create new memory for that else append to the existing list.

if(null == elements){
         elements = new ArrayList<>();}
        String numberOfElement = reader.readLine();
        elements.add(Integer.parseInt(numberOfElement));
        return elements;
    }

    public static List<Integer> getNumbers(BufferedReader reader, List elements) throws IOException{

// check if numbers have been initialised or not 
if(null == numbers ){
         numbers = new ArrayList<>();}

        String line = reader.readLine();                  
        for (String s : line.split("\\s+")) {                        
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        }    
        return numbers;
    }
```

Comment: I've tried to use the getter setter method but it returns null pointer. Apparently, the elements are not set. I'm wondering if this is the right way. public void setElements(List elements){
        this.elements = elements;
    }

Comment: Then for getter, I put  public List<Integer> getElements(){
        return this.elements;
    }

Comment: @www, from where did you invoked the setter method? In your case, I don't think you need to invoke any setter as you are populating the fields from within the class method.

Comment: I've managed to solve the setter problem. However, instead of getting values from all the input files, it only get values from one input file

Comment: Yes, you would get the values from the last file only as per the logic written, because the values of numbers and elements get overwritten in each iteration of you loop. It does not append values in existing list.